# Broken part, rear wheel, Hyundai Accent 2003

Tags: wheels, hyundai

I drove a long long way with my old car knowing I had to change the shock absorbers, and what needed to happen; happened. Something broke and I have now strange noise coming from one of the rear wheel (I will come back on that noise in another question). Usually I prefer to repair my old car by myself, both for fun and to save money. However, I have no idea what is the name and the purpose of the broken part. I will also need to drive tomorrow with the car, but wonder if it could be dangerous. Please look at the supplied picture and help me.

The car is a Hyundai Accent Gsi 2003 with a 1.6L engine.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be the stabilizer links which

> transfer weight between the left and right sides of a vehicle when it
>   turns, transferring some of the lateral force exerted in a turn to the
>   opposite side of the vehicle, which allows the body of the vehicle to
>   stay stable.

It is not dangerous to drive without it, but the ride will be less enjoyable :). The part cost between 8$ to 20$ and is really easy to change. I will do it tomorrow morning, I will come back if anything else comes up.

http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/moreinfo.php?pk=1416964&cc=1415797

**Edit:**
The part is easy to change if you do not account for rust. I had to cut it because of that. However, the new part was installed in about 2 min. I advise that you change the part asap when it brokes. Because I waited, the part scratched the inside of my rim. The sound I talked in my question was caused by the scratching which happened mostly when I turned on the left.